# Vb.net to insert txt.file into template Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I've been struggling with a minor project, yet it's supposed to be easy. I have a windows form app in vba to insert values into a excel file. 
It used to work in my company cause we had just a "couple" of data to enter. But now we are using txt files to gather the data to insert them in the excel file..

My problem is that we can't use macros anymore because there's always someone that changes something in the code.

My code WAS something like this:

```
Dim oApp As Excel.Application
    Try
        oApp = DirectCast(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        oApp.Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=TextBox1.Text, _
                                Origin:=Excel.XlPlatform.xlMSDOS, _
                                DataType:=Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, _
                                Comma:=False, Semicolon:=True, _
                                StartRow:=1)
        oApp.Visible = True
        oApp.Workbooks.Item(TextBox4.Text).SaveAs(Filename:=TextBox2.Text, _
                                               FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal)

        oApp.Workbooks.Item(TextBox3.Text).Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        'Quit Excel
        oApp.Quit()
        oApp = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("Success.", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
```

NOW i want to use a template Excel, and insert the data in sheet1, cause sheet2 has all the graphs and stuff..

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text)
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("data") 

   **With xlWorkSheet
        '~~> Directly type the values that we want
        .Range("A1").Value = "1"
        .Range("A2").Value = "2"
     End With**
End Sub
```

and i have no idea how to implement that. i don't know how to take the txt file and "place it" in sheet1..
Thank you all!

Comment: The usual syntax is xlworksheet.rows(1).cells(1).value = "1"

Comment: i dont get . can u explain pls? as i can predict it only adds the value 1 ..

Comment: The point is not to use "range" ... use .rows(rownum).cells(columnnum).value ... The index is not 0 based so "A1" would be .rows(1).cells(1) ... Are you actually trying to place the text file into excel - or read the file into excel?

Comment: but how does that help me? i'm doing this in order not to insert values manually, neither change code every time. that's why i gave the 1st example ..

Comment: What is it that youre looking to do? ... Here is how I understood the question - 1.) You have a text file 2.) you would like to read values from that text file into certain cells in excel as shown in the second example... The term you used -"WAS" - was signifying to me that you were trying to get away from the first example... can you give a step by step (1,2,3,4,5) on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: 1- i have a text file. 2- i have a formatted excel file with 2 sheets, one for data and other with graphs and stuff. 3- i want to insert the data from text file in sheet1 of my excel file.

Comment: insert it line by line or just attach the document into sheet 1?

Comment: once it's the "basic" operator that is going to do the action, i dont want him to open the excel file. that's why i'm making a UserInterface :)
anyway, the number of text lines isn't always the same, i cant predict how many lines it will have..

Comment: you honestly just lost me again when you used the word "UserInterface" .. what userInterface? sheet1? or are you trying to import the excel doc into windowsForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a text file line by line into excel.

```
Dim inFile as string() = file.ReadAllLines("yourFileName")
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text)
xlApp.Visible = True
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("data") 

for x as integer = 0 to inFile.length - 1
    dim splitLine as String() = infile(x).split(";"c)
    For y as integer = 0 to splitLine.length - 1 
         xlWorkSheet.rows(x + 1).Cells(y + 1).value = splitLine(y)
    Next
Next
```

if you just want to attach the file with an icon showing then I would use this.

```
xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Word.Document.8", "YourfilePath", False, False)
```

I believe should work.

Comment: Nice! it worked perfectly ! offtopic, where do i implement the separation delimiter, Semicolon:=True ? cumps

Comment: which one did you use? the top code or the bottom code? - Im going to assume the top code... There isnt anyway to import it using split by semicolon, you will need to do it progrmatically using .split(";"c)

Comment: i used the top one! yep that's what i thought.. but i'm still managing when/where to implement the split method.